# Sum involving Kaiser windows and trigonometric function

Tags: summation, signal-processing

I have a  sum ${\phi _1}$ where $w(n)$ is Kaiser window (centered at zero)), and ${T_s}$ is a sampling time.

$${\phi _1} = \sum_{n =  - N/2}^{N/2} {w{{(n)}^2}\cos } \left( {4\pi fn{T_s}} \right)$$

If I chose Kaiser (modified Bessel function) window parameter in such a way that ${\phi _1}$=0, is it possible to prove that sums ${\phi _2}$ and ${\phi _3}$ are also equal to zero or very small?

$$
\begin{split}
\phi _2
  &= \sum_{n =  - N/2}^{N/2} {w{{(n)}^2}\cos } \left( {4\pi fn{T_s}} \right){n^2}T_s^2\\
\phi _3
  &= \sum_{n =  - N/2}^{N/2} {w{{(n)}^2}\cos } \left( {4\pi fn{T_s}} \right){n^4}T_s^4
\end{split}
$$

In my numerical tests ${\phi _1}$ is of order $10^{-8}$, and ${\phi _2}$ and ${\phi _3}$ are even smaller, but I don't know how to prove it. I'm note sure is it the property of Kaiser window function, or it can be proved only considering that ${\phi _1}=0$. I also tried to prove this in integral form, 
but I did not succeed.

Any suggestion is welcome! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe analyze them in frequency domain.